# filteredArrayUsingPredicate and NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

**Hello,**

I search solution for my problem but I didn't found an answer.

My problem is that UISearchDisplayController no display anything.

**I think is this part of code :**

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c] %@", searchText];
    recherchemutablearray = [myObject filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];

}
```

***Because recherchemutablearray with [myObject filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate] return an array so as xcode say the pointer are incompatible...***

*I don't understand how i can do filteredUsingPredicate:resultPredicate but to return a NSMutableArray.*

After, it possible that there is an another problem in search fonction part code but I need to resolve this first.

Thanks

Comment: recherchemutablearray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[myObject filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate]];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a mutable copy like this

```
recherchemutablearray = [[myObject filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate] mutableCopy];
```